# No network on Ubuntu 21.10 - MSI PRO Z690-A WI-FI

Tags: networking, drivers, ethernet, 21.10

I have problem.
I haven't Ethernet and wifi on Ubuntu 21.10 (kernel 5.13.0.19-generic).
Motherboard: MSI PRO Z690-A WI-FI (Intel® I225-V 2.5Gbps LAN, Intel® Wi-Fi 6 module)

I executed command:

```
lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
```

Result:

```
Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:7af0] (rev 11) DeviceName: Onboard - Ethernet Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0074] Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

Command:

```
sudo dmesg | grep iwl
```

Return

```
[    3.668415] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.671658] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-63.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.671688] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-62.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.671700] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-61.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.671712] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-60.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.672225] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-59.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.672239] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-58.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.672250] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-57.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.672260] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-56.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.672272] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-55.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.672282] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-54.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.672292] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-53.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.672303] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-52.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.672316] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-51.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.672330] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-50.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.672340] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-49.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.672350] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-48.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.672361] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-47.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.672371] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-46.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.672382] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-45.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.672392] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-44.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.672403] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-43.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.672412] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-42.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.672422] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-41.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.672432] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-40.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.672443] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-39.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.672444] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: no suitable firmware found!
[    3.672448] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: minimum version required: iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-39
[    3.672450] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: maximum version supported: iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-63
[    3.672452] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: check git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `sudo dmesg | grep iwl` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this by updating to the 5.15 kernel, using the Tuxinvader PPA.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Had the same issue and updating to the latest stable kernel version 5.16 solved it for me.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/119080/how-to-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version-without-any-distro-upgrade

Answer (score 2):

It works out of the box in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, which comes with the kernel 5.15 (it has the drivers to support this device).

Comment: Since 22.04 is not released till April that is not an answer. If kernel 5.15 fixes it upgrade the kernel of 21.10 might be a fix.

Comment: Thx. I downloaded pre release 22.04 and it worked