# Intel AX201 not working with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Not working with other fix)

Tags: wireless, iwlwifi

I'm a total Ubuntu noob. Trying to get Ubuntu installed for one of my friends cause I build PCs for fun.

He requested for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I'm installing Ubuntu fine but I can't seem to get the Wifi module to work.

I remember back then when I did older versions of Ubuntu, there were similar issues with the AX200 as well.

Currently, running an Intel i9-12900K + Asus B660-A Strix motherboard.

Would appreciate any help with this. Thank you!

Edit #1:

ran `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` and got:

```
> Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-S PCH CNVi WiFi [8086:7af0] (rev 11)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Ethernet
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0074]
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

ran `sudo | dmesg | grep iwl` and got:

```
>[    1.764269] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    1.769945] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-63.ucode failed with error -2
[    1.769958] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-62.ucode failed with error -2
[    1.769966] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-61.ucode failed with error -2
[    1.769975] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-60.ucode failed with error -2
[    1.770038] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-59.ucode failed with error -2
[    1.770046] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-58.ucode failed with error -2
[    1.770108] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-57.ucode failed with error -2
[    1.770172] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-56.ucode failed with error -2
[    1.770181] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-55.ucode failed with error -2
[    1.770189] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-54.ucode failed with error -2
[    1.770197] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-53.ucode failed with error -2
[    1.770207] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-52.ucode failed with error -2
[    1.770215] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-51.ucode failed with error -2
[    1.770223] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-50.ucode failed with error -2
[    1.770232] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-49.ucode failed with error -2
[    1.770241] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-48.ucode failed with error -2
[    1.770249] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-47.ucode failed with error -2
[    1.770257] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-46.ucode failed with error -2
[    1.770267] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-45.ucode failed with error -2
[    1.770275] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-44.ucode failed with error -2
[    1.770284] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-43.ucode failed with error -2
[    1.770292] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-42.ucode failed with error -2
[    1.770300] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-41.ucode failed with error -2
[    1.770308] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-40.ucode failed with error -2
[    1.770317] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-39.ucode failed with error -2
[    1.770318] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: no suitable firmware found!
[    1.770320] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: minimum version required: iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-39
[    1.770321] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: maximum version supported: iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-63
[    1.770322] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: check git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git
```

Comment: Please [edit] to add the output of `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` and `sudo dmesg | grep iwl`

Comment: ok done as requested!

Comment: Is your system up to date? Try running `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`. You need a temporary Internet connection such as Ethernet or USB tethering to update.

Comment: yup seems like it is (ran the commands). yes im currently working off an Ethernet connection so have internet

Comment: Report a bug as the firmware version in Ubuntu's linux firmware is a higher version that what the kernel will load as it has iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-64 and the highest version the kernel will accept is iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-63

Comment: how should i go about doing this? sorry im like a total noob. the Ubuntu experience i have with troubleshooting is googling forums and copy pasting code into the terminal and praying that it works haha

Comment: What kernel are you using `uname -a`

Comment: @sceptism  Maybe try: `sudo apt install --reinstall linux-firmware`. Also, you are using kernel 5.13 right?

Comment: Please see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1384412/no-network-on-ubuntu-21-10-msi-pro-z690-a-wi-fi I suggest that you install kernel version 5.15.

Comment: yea i think it's 5.13 generic right now. ok will try to patch it up to 5.15. on a previous run i patched it to 5.16 i think but the wifi is still wonky. will try this tmr when i am with the PC

Comment: ok an update: i updated to 5.15 generic and a new problem emerges, now even the damn wired ethernet doesnt work haha omg this is driving me insane